# Output of vertex shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader

Tags: ipad, xcode8, ios10

When i run my app on ios 10 device and xcode 8 i'm getting the following message in debug console. Can any one know why this is happening

> ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1230.32.8.29.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1763: InfoLog SolidRibbonShader:
>   ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit/VectorKit-1230.32.8.29.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1764: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader

Comment: Would you be able to post your vertex and fragment shader source, or at least their inputs and outputs  ?

Comment: I have a same problem with the app that contains MapView.

Comment: This is clearly a problem with iOS as I have the most basic concept app with a map running on the 10.2 simulator and I get the same error. No error with 9.x simulator.

Comment: @AaronBratcher I would love to agree with you but... on my app everywhere I got this warning on the simulator make the app crash on a real iPhone 6s with ios 9.01

Answer (score 2):

The error is related to the Simulator's rendering methods & framework, as opposed to those of a real device.

The issue **should not reproduce on a real device**.

Please see a full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40255938/4268726)

Comment: I get this on a real device - iPhone 5 with iOS 10.3.2