# App freezes on main thread on iPhone 5c but not on iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, freeze

I'm working on an app with a navigation controller.
Swift + objective C

**Important note:**
This freeze happens 100% when testing on iPhone 5c and never happens when testing on iPhone 6s

The scenario is:

1. Go to TableViewController A
2. Touch an item of the list to reach TableViewController B
3. Go back to TVController A by pressing the top left arrow
4. The app shows TableViewController A but freezes right away

The UI is frozen but the app is still running.
If I press the Pause button (debug mode), I can see that the Thread 1 (Main thread) stack is:

```
0 semaphore_wait_trap
45 UIApplicationMain
46 main
47 start
```

I don't know where to start investigating so that I can find where the problem is.

[image: Stack on main thread]

Any ideas?

Comment: are you loading bulk of data in view controller life cycle?

Comment: not much no, only 3/4 items per list, memory doesn't even go high.

Comment: Can you include the entire call stack. Frames 1 through 44? They can be shown by using the buttons in the filter field at the bottom of the Xcode window.

Comment: I re-run the app and I get the stack until 33 only now. It seems that the map contained in the VC B makes the app crashes when deallocating...

Comment: some lines of source code of both VC A and B maybe could help. What contains VC B and what happens when VC B being deallocated?

Comment: You have a deadlock; the 5c doesn't have dual core while the 6s does. Do you have any `dispatch_sync` or similar?

Comment: Investigating. I ll update the post when i find out. Thanks a lot

Comment: What could be similar to a dispatch_sync?

Comment: Ok, I found the source of the problem here but I don't know why it is happening yet. I have a   var mapView:MKMapView? in my ViewControllerB  and if I don't create it, I don't have any freezes. Also, I just add it to the view and set VControllerB as it's delegate.. Investigating...

Comment: Other information: My MKMapView is inside a subview of VControllerB. I just create it in the subview init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day looking into it,
I finally found out that it was linked to MKMapView deinit.

Later I found this post about a very similar topic:

[WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608231/warning-output-of-vertex-shader-v-gradient-not-read-by-fragment-shader)

According to - the god - @mojuba , who found that the freeze was also related to the deinit phase offered a fix for the DEBUG mode. Because this issue seems to happen only in DEBUG...

I successfully applied his fix to my code as followed:

```
deinit {
    #if DEBUG
      // Xcode8/iOS10 MKMapView bug workaround
      if let mV = locationPickerView.mapView {
        VControllerB.unusedObjects.append(mV) // addObject:_mapView];
      }
    #endif
  }
```

NOTE that this produces a memory leak as mapView is never freed and kept within a static array of the VControllerB class.

NOTE 2: I reported the bug in Apple Bug Reporter while using Xcode 8.2.1 in Jan 27.

Answer (score 0):

This is a deadlock. Looks like you use dispatch_sync on main thread.
To fix problem - check other threads. In some thread you will find the code that is waiting when dispatched block ends ...

Comment: I added a breakpoint on all dispatch_sync within my program and the related Pods. none are triggered.

Comment: No need to add breakpoints. When you reach deadlock state pause application. And then look what is going on in other threads. For [example](https://i.imgur.com/5I0hmQB.png)