# Screen is blank white when started on the Xcode simulator [swift 3.0]

Tags: swift, runtime-error, startup

The screen is blank white when my app is started, but will go to normal once the screen is touched.

The error below comes up:

> ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1230.34.9.30.27/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1763: InfoLog SolidRibbonShader:
>
> ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1230.34.9.30.27/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1764: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you include some details about your project? What you're trying to do, what you're calling in your viewDidLoad, etc.? Your question is basically "My app doesn't work, why?"

Comment: Did you try `Xcode menu > Product > Clean` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vertex Shaders` generally run directly on the GPU for which it's compiled. In this case the `iOS` simulator doesn't physically have the GPU it needs to work with, hence the white screen.

Usually if you run the code on the physical device it should work, so try running there. Also check out this other [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608231/warning-output-of-vertex-shader-v-gradient-not-read-by-fragment-shader) with a similar error that might be of interest.

> A vertex shader is simply a tiny program that runs on the GPU, written
>   in a C++ like language called the Metal Shading Language.

↳ [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf)