# MKMapView Not Behaving Correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two UIViewControllers, both of which are embedded in UINavigationControllers. UIViewController A contains a button that, when clicked, presents UIViewController B which contains a MKMapView. UIViewController also contains a button that dismisses the view to go back to UIViewController A. But, the issue is that when I dismiss UIViewController B, UIViewController shows up but is frozen. Nothing is interactable and user interaction is disabled. However, I do see a semaphore_wait_trap when I pause the program in the debugger after the app freezes. But the weirdest thing is that the app works fine and does not freeze when I disconnect from XCode and use it then. So is this an XCode issue or am I doing something wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your device an iPhone 5c?

Comment: I am using an iPhone 5

Comment: Likely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39608231